# Kick off Bamboo Deployment from a Bamboo Build

Tags: bamboo

We've had success with the Bamboo Deployment Projects for deployment auditing and release management.

To simplify things, we want the ability of our build step (Bamboo Build Project) to have a manual deploy to QA and deploy to Prod Stage.

This would simply kick off the Bamboo Deployment Project with the current build artifact.

The only 2 solutions that I can think of to implement this is :
1) Stop using Bamboo Deployment Projects and simply script the deployment from an additional (manual) Bamboo step
2) Use the deployment Rest API hooks to kick off the deployment ( seems kind of smelly as I would have to inject the username/password again into the call)

Is there an alternative to said options ?

Note that I'm currently on Bamboo 5.6 (in the process of upgrading to latest version) ... so the Rest Deploy endpoints aren't available to me .. nor are the Deployment Triggers on successful Stage build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the bamboo deployment from the bamboo build.

Edit the deployment project.

Click on the Triggers button.

Add "After successful build plan" as a trigger.